# Cannot execute Compass because of Sass version

Tags: sass, compass-sass

All of a sudden, I get the following error message when running compass on OS X:

``` WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/Users/carlesandres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in ``block in setup': You have already activated sass 3.2.9, but your Gemfile requires sass 3.2.8. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/carlesandres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in ``setup'
    from /Users/carlesandres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:127:in ``setup'
    from /Users/carlesandres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in ``require'
    from /Users/carlesandres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:26:in ``<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlesandres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/compass:23:in ``load'
    from /Users/carlesandres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/compass:23:in ``<main>'
    from /Users/carlesandres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in ``eval'
    from /Users/carlesandres/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in ```'

I really don't know how to troubleshoot this.

**Update**: I am calling Compass from Grunt and a Yeoman-generated Gruntfile.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `compass clean` in your project and recompile.

If it doesn't help, try:

```
gem update --system
gem update
bundle install
compass clean
```

Comment: It didn't work. It seems to be a system-wide problem. I mean, it doesn't happen on a particular project, but on all projects.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it by updating the `sass-rails` gem.

```
bundle update sass-rails
```

I guess the old `sass-rails` gem was trying to force `sass v.3.2.8` which conflicted with the actually installed `3.2.9` installed version.